# Can windows 7 qualify for a windows XP volume license upgrade?

Tags: licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

We've got volume license for xp professional upgrade.
My predecessor thought that was enough to be compliant.

We can't buy xp anymore, but can 7 serve as basis for the volume license?

Another question:
Do we, for compliance, have to physically install windows first (retail license/copy), and then remove it and then install the volume license upgrade? Or is it enough to buy (and keep) enough copies of the retail version?

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to give you a 'black and white' answer for this but it depends very much on your region, country and existing licencing arrangement you may already have - there's really no 'one size fits' all answer I'm sorry - you're going to have to speak to MS directly :(

Answer (score 0):

You should call your microsoft advisor who can give you the correct and up-to-date information.